# Why is my Python RegEx in Power BI not working properly?

Tags: python, regex, powerbi, match

I have a dataset in PowerBI with the column `CouldContainColor`. Each row contains a string, some rows contain a color, some rows do not. Of the rows that contain a color, I want to put that color in a new column: `Color`.

Example data set:

```
CouldContainColor

helloyellow
thisisnocolor
purple
bluemonday
testgreentest
blackfriday
```

I want to create an if/else statement for all possible colors. However, this already goes wrong with the first if statement. For some reason he also sees matches, where there are no matches. The code:

```
import re

yellowMatch = re.search(r".*yellow.*", str(dataset["CouldContainColor"]))
if yellowMatch:
  dataset["Color"] = "Yellow"
else:
  dataset["Color"] = "Not Yellow"
```

The desired output:

```
CouldContainColor     Color

purple                Not Yellow
thisisnocolor         Not Yellow
helloyellow           Yellow
testtesttest          Not Yellow
testgreentest         Not Yellow
blackfriday           Not Yellow
```

But... when I run this, all rows get the value `Yellow` in the `Color` column. So, it says that all rows in the `CouldContainColor` column match the regex `.*yellow.*`.

And, when I use `re.match` instead of `re.search` , it doesn't see any matches. Then all the values in the `Color` column are `Not Yellow`. How can I make it work like I want? What's going wrong?

Comment: Do you want to do this natively in Power BI using M?

Comment: Not in M, but in a Python script inside the Query Editor

Comment: Not familiar with Python. So I would leave this for someone else to help you with. But if you do prefer native M, just so you know you can take care of this using M. For complex regex, you can also do regex using javascript directly inside M without any dependency at all.